# Is there anyway to make cherokee server portable?

Tags: webserver, portability, portable-applications, cherokee

I develop on different machines. I use MAMP, I have it installed on my dropbox folder and created symbolic links to the applications folder. That way if I work one day on my desktop and make changes to lets say a database schema and next day I work from my laptop I won't have to do any db migration stuff the same applies for all the apache virtual hosts I have setup using MAMP. Everything is portable.

I recently started using Cherokee server and I like it a lot. I would like to replace MAMP with Cherokee but first I need to be able to make it portable. I don't want to have to configure multiple virtualhosts, settings, etc on multiple machines.

Is there anyway I can setup Cherokee to be as portable as MAMP?

What if I want to run Cherokee from a thumbdrive?

Comment: Thanks, I moved it there: http://serverfault.com/questions/88926/is-there-anyway-to-make-cherokee-server-portable

Comment: HOw do you create a sysmbolic link again could you email me the answer at yaxar.murat@gmail.com

I have been looking allover for it